5 reviewers assigned to a paper, but 6 reviewers listed as readers when adding an official comment on the paper. How is that possible?
I have access to the program chairs console of a venue in OpenReview. I see on the Reviewers Assignment page that 5 reviewers are assigned to a paper, but 6 reviewers are listed as potential readers when adding an official comment on the paper. How is that possible?
